# Django - validating m2m relationship

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have the following models:

```
class Question(Model):
    # ...

class Choice(Model):
    question = ForeignKey(Question)
    # ...

class AnswerToQuestion(Model):
    user = ForeignKey(User)
    question = ForeignKey(Question)
    selected_choices = ManyToManyField(Choice)
```

What I would like to do is make sure that the values inside of `selected_choices` will always be choices belonging to the question stored in the `question` field.

This is what I tried in the `clean` method of `AnswerToQuestion`:

```
    def clean(self):
        super().clean()
        if self.pk and self.selected_choices.exclude(question=self.question).exists():
            raise ValidationError("Invalid choice(s)")
```

However, this does not work as expected: since the m2m relationship is updated after the actual model save, if I try and associate an invalid choice, this will work fine, and then every subsequent save will fail because I *already* have an invalid associated choice.

Is there another way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: why not remove self.pk from clean method?

Comment: I need to check if self.pk is not None because, the first time the model is created, Django can't check its m2m relationship as the model doesn't have a pk yet. This has nothing to do with my issue though

Comment: how are you using this model? through adminsite, forms, or restapi? Maybe you can override there.

Comment: Mostly through the serializers of DRF. However, I want to keep all validation as close to the model itself as possible to achieve a better separation of concerns and stability (e.g. in the event I change the way my models are interacted with in the future).

Answer (score 1):

The other way may be to use a [through-model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through).

Say you have it like this:

```
class Choice(Model):
    question = ForeignKey(Question)
    # ...

class AnswerToQuestion(Model):
    user = ForeignKey(User)
    question = ForeignKey(Question)
    selected_choices = ManyToManyField(Choice, through="AnswerToQuestionChoiceM2M", through_fields=("answer", "choice"))


class AnswerToQuestionChoiceM2M(Model):
    answer = ForeignKey(AnswerToQuestion)
    choice = ForeignKey(Choice)
    # ...
```

Then you can save the relationship directly:

```
AnswerToQuestionChoiceM2M(answer_id=..., choice_id=...).save()
```

and in case the relationship exists, the database will tell you, so you catch the exception:

```
try:
    AnswerToQuestionChoiceM2M(answer_id=..., choice_id=...).save()
except IntegrityError:
    raise ValidationError("Invalid choice(s)")
```

This approach is concurrency-friendly, because the actual validation happens inside a database. Databases are good at handling concurrent transactions, so you don't have to.

This approach will also allow you to add more information `AnswerToQuestionChoiceM2M` in case you need to do so at some point. For example, you may want to safe the `datetime` when the choice happened.

This approach does require more code. Also, working with M2M relationships directly may feel weird if you are not used to it.

Comment: I don't dislike the idea in general, but in my case I really wouldn't want to create a through model to keep the complexity down: in my application, I really just use `selected_choice` as an array, conceptually; also, I would have to mess with the way my serializers assign to the field. I believe there has to be a way to perform validation on the field: for example, if you supply the PK of a model that doesn't exist at all, Django is able to catch and report a ValidationError, so some additional code might be inserted at that spot, if I can identify it.

Comment: Also, I believe you did understand the question correctly, but just to clarify: "and in case the relationship exists" - this is not the problem. What I want to check is that each of the `selected_choices` of an `AnswerToQuestion` is a choice for the same question as the one referenced by the `AnswerToQuestion`, not that it isn't already related to my model instance - that kind of check is surely performed automatically by Django & the db.

Comment: Just to be clear, Django does create a similar table (like through) in DB even though you don't specify it.

Comment: I understand how m2m relationships work. I just don't want to have to manually manage it in this case.

Comment: @SamueleB. oh I understand the question now, thank you for clarification. How about then not checking it using the database (the `self.selected_choices.exclude(question=self.question).exists()` part), and instead query `self.question.choices.all()`, and then check if `self.selected_choices` are all in  `self.question.choices.all()`?

Comment: I would also consider checking this condition inside a serializer/form, not the model. I don't think that django-model is the level for this type of validation, they are pretty rigid when it comes to what you can and can't check

Comment: Oh, I found the answer to my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74314407/django-validating-m2m-relationship/74314908?noredirect=1#comment131199278_74314407). Then I would probably go for [python-level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74314407/django-validating-m2m-relationship/74314908?noredirect=1#comment131200039_74314908) check

Comment: Although I would suggest you to consider to do the [validation at the edge of the system](https://www.cosmicpython.com/book/appendix_validation.html#_validating_at_the_edge), not inside it. The business logic validation doesn't really belong at the database model layer